# What replaced the "access CiviCRM" permissions?

Tags: permissions, administer

There used to be a CiviCRM permission in the CMS for "access CiviCRM" - and most of the resources mention this.  But its gone now (CiviCRM v 5.33, Drupal 7.78) and I need to give some users contact, event, activity, contribution creation & edit permissions but not "administer CiviCRM" permission.

The result is that the CMS role "CiviCRM user" (different from "CiviCRM Administrator") cannot access CiviCRM unless I give full CiviCRM administration privileges.

What is the current best practice for giving this set of permissions?

Answer (score 3):

Internally it's still "access CiviCRM". The label changed to "access CiviCRM backend and API".

https://github.com/civicrm/civicrm-core/commit/d9a37cbcc18a593635360ce05f236dcd9ec7d93e#diff-410497db8c86f6ba1a897c533db8f391a25d2cee7b12852bb743b2dbed82d86aR764